# Convert and move large number of files using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Hi I need help with creating a script that needs to:

1. Convert large number of Excel(both .xlsx and .xls) and csv files to google sheets
2. Move these converted files into a desired google drive folder
3. Remove original files from the source folder

I already tried creating one but I always hit the 6 min execution limit. I know it can be done using batches but I just started using Google script and this concept is really advanced for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my current script:

```
function importXLSX(){
  var folderBId = "IdOfMyDestinationFolder";

  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('IdOfMySourceFolder').searchFiles('title != "nothing"');
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xlsx') >-1 || name.indexOf('.csv') >-1 ){ 
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = {
        title : name+'_converted',
        parents: [{id: folderBId}] //  Added
      };
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
        convert: true
      });
      // Drive.Files.remove(ID);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks, Filip

Comment: Hi Filip, have you tried this: To automatically convert all future uploads of Office files to Google Sheets:

In Drive, at the top, click Settings ""and thenSettings.
Next to Convert uploads, turn on Convert uploaded files to Google Docs editor format.
Note: Previously uploaded files will not be converted.

Comment: Hi @MatiasCG, thank you for your answer. I tried it but in my case, it didn't solve the problem. All files that are located in the source google drive folder are gmail attachments downloaded using another Google Apps script. So the files are not uploaded "naturally" and all the formats are the same as the attachments.

Comment: About `I already tried creating one but I always hit the 6 min execution limit.`, can you provide your current script? And, how many files do you want to convert from XLSX to Spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, there are about 130 files that I need to convert. The script is too long for a comment so I edited it into my post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thank you for your answer. I tried following your flow and implemented the script. When there are just a few files in the folder it works as expected, but when I tried to convert the large number of files I have, they all end up in My Drive instead of the Destination Folder. Is there something that could cause this? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `but when I tried to convert the large number of files I have, they all end up in My Drive instead of the Destination Folder. Is there something that could cause this?`, in the current stage, when the file is put to the specific folder using Drive API, first, the file is put to the root folder and then the file is moved to the specific folder. When the number of files is large, it is considered that the processing is delayed. So, how about waiting for finishing all processes?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your reply. Sorry again. I tried converting just 30 files and always waited for the script to end also after it ended I waited for an hour if they get moved and they are still left in the root folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful in your situation, again.